# web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction - transaction not located

Tags: web3js

I am using web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction and infura.io on mainnet. I want to call my smart contract's whitelisting function. I have no problems calling this function directly, however, when using web3 to call it, a transaction hash is produced, but it is never located. e.g.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5d127fde285fc4821eb99dceb1a96ac1122a1dd543c92f8685fd19f51aa95a6c

It seems like a gas issue, but I have tried with many different gas prices and limits, what else could be the problem?

Sometimes I get the error "Error: Transaction was not mined within750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!"

```
exports.addToWhitelist = function(req, res) {

var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/' + 
process.env.INFURA_KEY));

 var userAddress = req.user.ethereumAddress;

  var ownerAddress = process.env.OWNER_ADDRESS;

  var helper = {
        ensureBuffer: function(bufferOrString) {

            if (typeof bufferOrString === "string") {
                return new Buffer(bufferOrString, 'hex');
            } else {
                return bufferOrString;
            }
        }
    };

  var key = helper.ensureBuffer(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);

  var userAddress = req.address;

  var crowdsaleAbi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_buyer","type":"address"}],"name":"addToEarlylist","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]');

  var crowdsaleContract = new web3.eth.Contract(crowdsaleAbi, process.env.CROWDSALE_CONTRACT);

  web3.eth.getGasPrice().then(function(result)
    {
      var methodData = crowdsaleContract.methods.addToEarlylist(userAddress).encodeABI();

      var fTx = {
            nonce: 0,
            gasPrice: 0,
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(800000),
            data: methodData,
            from: ownerAddress
          };

      fTx.gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(result);

      console.log('gas price: 40 gwei');

      web3.eth.getTransactionCount(ownerAddress)
        .then(function(result) {

          fTx.nonce = web3.utils.toHex(result + 1);

          var txx = new Tx(fTx);
          txx.sign(key);

          console.log(fTx);
          var sTx = txx.serialize();

          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + sTx.toString('hex'))
          .on('transactionHash', function (hash) {
              console.log("trans hash: " + hash)
          })
          .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
              console.log("receipt: " + receipt)
          })
          .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
               console.log("conf: " + confirmationNumber, receipt)
          })
          .on('error', (e) => {
              console.log("Sending Error: " + e)
          });

        }).catch(function(error) {console.log(error)});;

    }).catch(function(error) {console.log('gas price error ' + error)});

}
```

Comment: Change the `nonce` from 0 to something higher.

Comment: The nonce isn't 0, it is just 0 initially. it is taken from ' web3.eth.getTransactionCount(ownerAddress) + 1'

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?